# Splitting string by delimiter does not split correctly

Tags: c, string, split

I have a function that has to spilt a line read from file into words by some delimiters (delimiters check is made by another function) but my code splits the string by delimiters which are not included in the delimiters' list [an array of delimiters]:

```
void getIdentifiers() {
    FILE *filePointer;
    char fileName[FILENAME_MAX], line[256], identifier[100];

    char delimiter[] = {
        '[', ']', '(', ')', ';', '!', '=', '>', '<', '|', '*', '/', ':',
        '&', '%', ' ', '\n', '\t', '"', '{', '}', ',', '-', '+', '#' };

    int cnt = 0, inWord = 0, isString = 0, isSingleLineComment = 0, isMultiComment = 0, isChar = 0;

    printf("\n Enter filename:\n");
    flush(stdin);

    if (!fgets(fileName, FILENAME_MAX, stdin)) {
        printf("\nError reading filename");
        return;
    }

    if (fileName[strlen(fileName) - 2] != 'c' || fileName[strlen(fileName) - 3] != '.') {
        printf("\nInvalid source file name\n");
        return;
    }

    fileName[strlen(fileName) - 1] = '\0';

    filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (filePointer == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening file");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0]), filePointer) != NULL) {
        if (ferror(filePointer)) {
            printf("\nError reading the file");
            return;
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        while (line[i]) {
            //multi line comment check
            if (line[i] == '/' && line[i + 1] == '*')
                isMultiComment = 1;

            //single line comment
            if (line[i] == '/' && line[i + 1] == '/')
                isSingleLineComment = 1;

            //ending multi line comment
            if (line[i] == '*' && line[i + 1] == '/' && isMultiComment == 1) 
                isMultiComment = 0;

            //checking for string
            if (line[i] == '"' && isString == 0)
                isString = 1;
            else if (line[i] == '"' && isString == 1)
                isString = 0;

            //check if assignment char is in quote
            if (line[i] == '\'' && isChar == 0) 
                isChar = 1;
            else if (line[i] == '\'' && isChar == 1)
                isChar = 0;

            //splitting textline into words
            if (inWord==0) {
                if (!isDelimiter(delimiter, line[i])) {
                    inWord = 1;
                    identifier[j] = line[i];
                    j++;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                //ending word
                if (isDelimiter(delimiter, line[i])) {
                    inWord = 0;
                    identifier[j] = 0;
                    j = 0;

                    // identifier checking
                    if (!isString && !isMultiComment && !isSingleLineComment 
                        && !isChar) {
                        cnt++;
                        printf("\n%s", identifier);
                    }
                } else {
                    identifier[j] = line[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        isSingleLineComment = 0;
    }
    printf("\n Number of identifiers is  %d", cnt);
}

int isDelimiter(char *delim, char c) {
    int i = 0;
    while (delim[i]) {
        if (delim[i] == c)
            return 1;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The file that I try to read contains:

```
Turbo direct injection
```

The expected output is:

```
Turbo
direct
injection
```

But I got:

```
Turbo
di
ect
inject
o
```

Comment: It helped but the last word is not shown now

Comment: Besides treating `delimiter` as a null-terminated string when it's not, there are also other things that are... Well, weird (or wrong): First of all, calling `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Even if some C libraries implement it, it's not portable and should be avoided. Also, since `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be `1`, the expression `sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])` is equal to `sizeof(line)`. And what happens if `fileName` is shorter than two characters? Or longer than `FILENAME_MAX`?

Comment: declare isDelimiter before to use it, or move its definition above its use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a newline at the end of your input file ?

{edit add}

your program supposes each word had a delimiter after it, because the word is print only when `isDelimiter(delimiter, line[i])` is true (*inWord* being not 0), so if the file contains exactly *Turbo direct injection* (last character is 'n') injection is not shown

Comment: No, there is not a new line in the end of the file

Comment: this is why injection is not shown, your program supposes there is a delimiter after each word

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I supposed it is enough for him to understand, I added more in my answer, thank you for the down vote lol

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the `delimiter` character array is not a proper C string: you must add an explicit null byte at the end of the initializer:

```
    char delimiter[] = { '[', ']', '(', ')', ';', '!', '=', '>', '<',
        '|', '*', '/', ':', '&', '%', ' ', '\n', '\t', '"', '{', '}',
        ',', '-', '+', '#', '\0' };
```

Alternately, you could use a string constant:

```
    char delimiter[] = "[]();!=><|*/:&% \n\t\"{},-+#";
```

There are many more issues in your code:

- `flush(stdin)` has undefined behavior. If you mean to discard pending input from a previous call to `scanf()`, use an explicit loop.
- you should strip the trailing newline from `fileName` but not assume it is present. Use this one liner for example:

  ```
  fileName(strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
  ```
- you should verify the string length before accessing characters from the end. As coded, you have undefined behavior if the user enters a single character before the newline. First strip the newline then use this:

  ```
  size_t len = strlen(fileName);
  if (len < 3 || fileName[len - 2] != '.' || fileName[len - 1] != 'c') {
      printf("\nInvalid source file name\n");
      return;
  }
  ```
- There is no need for `sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0])`, `char` is `1` by definition in C.
- testing for `ferror(filePointer)` is meaningless if `fgets()` returns a valid pointer.
- You must increment `i` by 2 when matching `/*` otherwise you will misinterpret the sequence `/*/`, furthermore, you should not keep scanning inside the comment for `//` and/or string delimiters.
- you must break from the loop if matching `//` for the same reasons.
- if you are inside a string, you should recognise `\` as an escape character and accept `\"` as part of the string. Furthermore, you should not scan for comments inside a string.
- the same remark for character constants.
- you may have buffer overflows if the file contains very long identifiers (> 99 chars), including inside comments or strings.
- you forget to close the source file

Comment: Sir, I've seen your lots of brilliant answers. Could you look at http://t1p.de/xu1t     ??

Answer (score -1):

```
char **mystrtok(const char *str, const char *del, int alowempty)
{
  char **result = NULL;
  const char *end = str;
  size_t size = 0;
  int extrachar;

  while(*end)
  {
    if((extrachar = !!strchr(del, *end)) || !*(end + 1))
    {
        /* add temp variable and malloc / realloc checks */
        /* free allocated memory on error */
        if(!(!alowempty && !(end - str)))
        {
            extrachar = !extrachar * !*(end + 1);
            result = realloc(result, (++size + 1) * sizeof(*result));
            result[size] = NULL;
            result[size -1] = malloc(end - str + 1 + extrachar);
            strncpy(result[size -1], str, end - str + extrachar);
            result[size -1][end - str + extrachar] = 0;
        }
        str = end + 1;
    }
    end++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: it is funny because you have a problem similar to Yusmen Rashidov, if the input string is not terminated by a separator the last character is lost (not the word that time except if the last word length is 1), for instance `mystrtok("azety qsd", " ", 0)` returns `{"azerty", "qs", 0}` ( `mystrtok("azety qsd ", " ", 0)` returns `{"azerty", "qsd", 0}` )

Comment: Additional remark, why to return NULL if _str_ length is 1 ? it seems more practical if `mystrtok("a", " ", 0)` returns `{ "a", 0}` no ?

Comment: Yep. sorted               -----------------

Comment: I see you very like the '!' :-) In `extrachar = !extrachar * !*(end + 1);` to use a '*' for a _and_ seems expensive no ?

Comment: @bruno No. For two reasons: 1. the generated code will not `multiply` or `and` the results. 2. Even if it will multiply integer multiplication on all modern platforms (including 8 bits AVR uCs) is same fast as `and`. This time your comment is 100% wrong